# setup.py: what is a difference between entry points and cmdclass?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, distutils

While learning the structure of `setup.py`, I came across two terms: `entry_points` and `cmdclass`.

I read the document of `setuptools` and `distutils`. With the help of that, and some information I found online, I came to the conclusion that those two are one and the same. Specifically:

Those two are used to add custom commands, or can be used to add hooks to the existing commands.

But, when I checked the `setup.py` files of some popular packages, I found that those two properties are being used together. For e.g. see `setup.py` of [`numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/setup.py) package.

Could you explain me the use of those two properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmdclass` is a way to modify behaviour of the very `setup.py`. For example you can override `build` or `install` commands to extend them.

`entry_points` are similar to `scripts`, they declares scripts that will be created on installation. Those scripts are intended to run by users.

Comment: So, using both cmdclass and entry_Points I can change the script @ install time?

Comment: What do you mean? Those two are different things, only one installs script that will be used later bu the user. What does it mean "change the script @ install time"?

Comment: well what I meant was the arbitrary code execution @ the run time - for e.g. author uses cmdclass to do the same: https://github.com/mschwager/0wned

Comment: Both can be used to run any code. `cmdclass` to run code at installation time, `entry_points` to run code when a user run scripts.